# Hybrid Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am trying to implement multiple hybrid inheritance in python, it is giving answer also but I am wondering what is the reason behind the sequence of the answer, for this code:

```
class GrandPa:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Grand Pa")

class Father(GrandPa):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Father")

class Mother(GrandPa):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Mother")


class child(Father, Mother):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("Child")

c = child()
```

OUTPUT

```
Grand Pa
Mother
Father
Child
```

In the child class we have taken Father class before the mother, so shouldn't Father be printed before Mother? Is there any logic behind this sequence?

Comment: It happens like that because of the MRO (method resolution order). Try calling `c.__mro__`

Comment: You can read more in the documentation of multiple inheritance and MRO: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always consult [`__mro__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) to find out what is going on:

```py
print(c.__class__.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.child'>, <class '__main__.Father'>, <class '__main__.Mother'>, <class '__main__.GrandPa'>, <class 'object'>)
```

And indeed `Father` is coming before `Mother` in this chain.

But, when you are chaining calls like this, that's what actually happens:

```py
class GrandPa:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Grand Pa")

class Father(GrandPa):
    def __init__(self):
        print('f', super())
        super().__init__()
        print("Father")

class Mother(GrandPa):
    def __init__(self):
        print('m', super())
        super().__init__()
        print("Mother")


class child(Father, Mother):
    def __init__(self):
        print('c', super())
        super().__init__()
        print("Child")

c = child()
```

I have added `print(super())` to all methods to illustrate what is going on inside the callstack:

```
c <super: <class 'child'>, <child object>>
f <super: <class 'Father'>, <child object>>
m <super: <class 'Mother'>, <child object>>
Grand Pa
Mother
Father
Child
```

As you can see, we start with the `Child`, then go to `Father`, then to `Mother`, and only after that `GrandPa` is executed. Then the controll flow is returned to `Mother` and only after it goes to `Father` again.

In real life use-cases, it is not recommended to overuse the multiple inheritance. It might be a huge pain. Composition and mixins are way easier to comprehend.